# How to extract data from array and prepare for sql INSERT statment?

Tags: php, arrays, insert, foreach

here is my problem:

```
$paki=$each_item['quantity'];

$test=array("item"=>array("id"=>$item_id),"quan"=>array("q"=>$paki), "price"=>array("pricee"=>$price) );


//Foreach for display

foreach ($test as $indeks1 => $vrednost1){
  foreach ($vrednost1 as $indeks2 => $vrednost2){


echo "[".$indeks1."][".$indeks2."]=".$vrednost2."<br>";

  }
}
```

This working fine, when I echo, I get the proper results, but I need to that information put into next statement:

```
INSERT INTO stavke(pr_id,kolicina,price) VALUES ('$item_id','$kolicina','$price')
```

So,my problem is how to get data for: '$item_id','$kolicina','$price' and put them in to statement.

I try different extract functions, but without result..

Thanks in advance,

Pavle

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get `id` and `price` from your array `$test`?

```
$id = $test['item']['id'];
$price = $test['price']['pricee'];
// $kolicina is not in your code, so no idea where to get that from!
```

Why don't you make a simpler array?

```
$test = array('id' => $id, 'quantity' => $quantity, 'price' => $price);
```

Then, you access the elements as...

```
INSERT INTO blabla (a,b,c) VALUES ($test['id'],$test[$quantity],$test['price']);
```

Comment: My first idea was like yours, to be simple, but you know when you start to work you go too deep:) So, my crucial problem  is: If I have 2 values for item_id and price in our array, I want to insert them,one by one, for example if we have id_item(1,2) price(1o,20), for my first step to insert id_item=1 and price=10, next step id_item=2 and price=20. My idea was to use for loop and to try to index all data for every step of loop... Once again, I thanks for your time.. If I found solution in midtime, I will post hier. Thanks a lot! Pavle